# What is LaTeX and How Can I Get Started Using It?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, latex, typing

For physics and math classes, it would be very useful to be able to type out equations with symbols and such.  I believe that LaTeX allows you to do this, but I am not sure.  So, what is LaTeX exactly and what is the best way to get started?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX

Comment: Why vote to close this? This is a very legitimate question to me.

Comment: I have read that article.  I am still unsure if this does what I believe it does.  Also, my question has two parts.  The Wiki article shows many ways to get started, yet I was asking what the best way was.  Thank you.

Comment: If you want to take notes during class, I suggest you write on paper. LaTeX formulas are pretty damn hard to type live during a lecture unless you're a fast typist and are very familiar with LaTeX.

Comment: @DanielBeck: I'm assuming the OP is a *student* and wants to hand in papers with the equations.

Comment: @MetroGnome With that comment, the question can be considered *subjective and argumentative*, asking for *the best* way to do things. You didn't even bother mentioning your operating system, so others can rattle off a few editor recommendations.

Comment: Why are the closes on this as "off topic?" It's related to computer software, so it's completely on topic.

Comment: I really do not understand the issue here.  
@DanielBeck, Mark is correct.  Also, I am a new user who would simply like to get started with a difficult program.  All I am doing is asking a more experienced user to assist me in choosing the right path.  My OS is Windows 7 home 64 bit.

Comment: You might be able to find good information readily available on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). @Mark replied to my paper suggestion, but that isn't why I voted to close. I remember reading on meta (IIRC) that something that can be answered with a Wikipedia article or the #1 Google hit probably shouldn't be on this site -- and it seemed/seems to be that kind of question.

Comment: @Daniel, [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) is the flowchart to determining if a question is too simple to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX is a typesetting language. It alows you to use write equations and many other things.

A good place to start learning it would be this website:
http://latex101.wikispaces.com/Syllabus